# User's location in google maps api for ios

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps-api-3

I', writing an app on swift language. I was just following this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/81103/introduction-google-maps-ios-sdk-swift). Why does the user's location look like this?

[image]

Comment: Just look at the square around the user's location

Comment: Are you facing this on a device? This is a known issue in Apple's simulator but it shouldn't be the case on device.